# Trying to make my labels legible in scipy dendrogram

Tags: python, scipy, dendrogram

I have written the following code in Python to create a dendrogram to cluster different countries based on some COVID data:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

covid = pd.read_csv('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv')
covid2 = covid[covid['date']=='2020-10-31']
covid3 = covid2[['iso_code','total_cases_per_million','new_cases_per_million',
               'total_deaths_per_million','new_deaths_per_million',
               'reproduction_rate','positive_rate','total_tests_per_thousand',
             'icu_patients_per_million','hosp_patients_per_million']].dropna()

covid_data = covid3.drop(columns='iso_code')

countries = str(covid3['iso_code'].tolist())

clusters = linkage(covid_data,method='complete')

dendrogram(clusters,
       labels=countries,
       leaf_rotation=90,
       leaf_font_size=8)
plt.show()
```

The list of labels (countries) contains three letter codes for each country (e.g. 'AUT', 'BEL', 'BGR', 'CZE', 'DNK', 'EST', 'GBR', 'HUN', 'IRL', 'ITA', 'LUX', 'PRT', 'SVN', 'USA').

However these labels are illegible in the resulting dendrogram. Instead of being able to read the 3 letter code for each country, I can only see one letter for each country (and for some countries I can only see part of a letter).

I have tried changing the orientation of my dendrogram to 'right' but I can still only see partial information for the labels.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can make all three letters appear for each of the countries in the dendrogram labels?

Comment: Did you try `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()`? And `plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=8)`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions JohanC. I tried both of those but neither seemed to have any effect.

Comment: Turns out the issue was with the str() function used when defining the country names. Instead of: 'countries = str(covid3['iso_code'].tolist())', I should have just used 'countries = covid3['iso_code'].tolist()'. Now my dendrogram labels work.